# How to create an app to consume real time notifications

Tags: java, android, browser, push-notification, real-time

I want to create an app to consume real time data from an API. This API give me information about different temperatures. When a certain temperature is exceeded my app need to notify the event to the user.

This app need to run in Android and a web browser. So, my problem is the architecture... My app need to be a websocket or a REST API?

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: use GCM.... this is the best for what you are looking for....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a notification service, and google has something like that for us...

[image]

## how does this works??

Take a look at  the image below,

you need to register your android app in the google service, and your web interface will need an id, so everytime you want to push something to the android, your web interface instead will push it to the google server with the Id of the app, then google (no matter how) will localize your app, and even if its not running, they will get the notification,

behind the scenes there is a couple of thing that you must do, bu nothing like launching rockets from the NASA.

I will suggest to take a look to some [tutorials](http://javapapers.com/android/android-device-to-device-messaging-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-via-http/)
in order to start with the registration of your app, get the api key etc etc..

Comment: I have a doubt. The API that provides me temperatures is developed from other people. This API must hosted and register in GCM?

Comment: then that changes the hole story.... if the API is developed by a 3er party, then you are going to ask for their own push services, otherwise you will need to go for a RESTful service(and that means you need to poll the server constantly, which is not so good idea...)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Xoce showed, Amazon has the [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/) service which will push notifications to you.  Or, if you application is a web based application inside of a native (i.e. Cordova), I've used [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/) for JavaScript based events.

A word of caution though - you'll need to define "real time" for your application.  There will be a slight latency between the event and what your application sees no matter what stack you choose.  When I think real time I think in terms of microseconds of delay.  You may have seconds of delay.  If this is a "hey, your house temperature is above a threshold" type of application then that is fine.  If this is "hey, your nuclear reactor temperature is above a threshold" then this may not be the way to go.